# Redirecting action to another controller within the same area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to get my site to run a redirection on a successful login.  I keep all my membership routes in an area.

```
/membership/login/index
/membership/profile/index
```

I've tried the following two to try and get this to work - the login is successful but the redirect doesn't do anything but change the address.  I've tried the following but they all come out with the same result

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Login loginViewModel)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToRoute(new { Area = "Membership", 
               Controller = "Profile", Action="Index" });
}
```

results in this

```
http://mysite.com/Membership/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmembership%2fProfile
```

Then my next effort

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { Area = "Membership" });
....
http://mysite.com/Membership/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmembership%2fProfile
```

And finally

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
... 
http://mysite.com/Membership/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmembership%2fProfile
```

Comment: HTTP POST cannot redirect.  But I don't know the workaround, other than changing it to a GET.  If you change it to `HttpGet`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks, good to know, I don't know the ins and outs of http well enough

Comment: It seems your login is not successful. You are allways redirecting back to login again. Could you show full code of your ActionResut?

Comment: I've debugged it, the code in the samples is definitely being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly redirect a HTTP post (what you can't do is to have it redirected and then expect the redirected response to also be POST). What's happening here is that you are successfully redirecting the request to the correct page, but the page in question requires authentication and since the user is not authenticated, the request is sent back to the login page again. You should do the redirect *after* you set your cookies (or perform whatever authentication mechanism you are doing).

Comment: Makes perfect sense, will give it a try in the morning

Comment: This was indeed the case, the authentication wasn't working properly

Answer (score 1):

You have to save coockies before redirecting..

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("UserName or somthing",false/true);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { Area = "Membership" });
```

Now it will work..